# How to write If ELSE statement in Google Sheets to Hide columns dependent on cell value

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets, conditional-statements

Trying to write and if statement in **Google** sheets to hide a range of columns dependent on cell value in **D4**

```
If D4 == 1 hide columns H:AA
If D4 == 2 hide columns O:AA
Else show A:AA
```

**Code below:**

```
var cell = "D4";
var value1 = 1;
var value2 = 2;
var value3 = 3;
var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

function HideColumn(); {
    If(cell == value1) {
        activeSheet.hideColumn("H:AA");
        Else If(cell == value2) {
            activeSheet.hideColumn("O:AA");
            Else If(cell == value3) {
                activeSheet.unhideColumn("H:AA");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Your code needs some modifications:

```
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var value1 = 1;
var value2 = 2;
var value3 = 3;
var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var cell = activeSheet.getRange("D4").getValue();

function HideColumn() {
  if(cell == value1) {
      activeSheet.hideColumns(8, (27-8+1));
  }
  else if(cell == value2) {
        activeSheet.hideColumns(15, (27-15+1));
  }
   else if(cell == value3) {
      activeSheet.hideColumns(8, (27-8+1));
  }
}
```

Explanations:

1. If you want to hide several columns rather than one, you need to use the methods [`hideColumns(columnIndex, numColumns)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hidecolumnscolumnindex,-numcolumns) (mind the notation)
2. The `if` and `else if` statements should be separate rather than nested (note the brackets)
3. `if` and `else` statements in Apps Script are written in low case
4. The correct way to obtain the content of a cell is `var cell = activeSheet.getRange("D4").getValue();`

I hope my answer was helpful for you.